# Recovering a checkpoint after reaching NaN loss?

Tags: tensorflow, loss, checkpoint

I'm training an RNN and sometime overnight the loss function reached NaN. I've been reading that a solution to this is to decrease the learning rate. When attempting to restart training from the (only) checkpoint I have and using a smaller learning rate, I still get NaN. Does this mean my checkpoint is beyond repair? Is there a way to either recover this one OR use tf.train.Saver in such a way that I am guaranteed a version of the model before it reaches a point of no return?

Comment: If learning rate was your issue, I would expect to see NaN from the very first epoch, not after many iterations.

Answer (score 0):

If your checkpoint has `NaN` values in it, there is probably not a lot you can do to recover it. I guess you could replace the NaNs with something else, but that isn't that principled.

You probably want to see if there is an earlier checkpoint without `NaN` values. `tf.train.Saver` keeps up to 5 previous checkpoints by default, for precisely this sort of reason:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver

Hope this helps!